How can you add different staticConfigs in Prometheus blackboxprobes to use it in Grafana?
I have this blackboxprobes yaml for prometheus ->
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Probe
metadata:
  name: 2xx-endpoints-how_it_works
spec:
  interval: 30s # Interval at which targets are probed
  module: http_2xx # Use the http_2xx module
  prober:
    url: blackbox: 9115 # Point to your blackbox instance, will always be 'blackbox:9115 
  targets:
    staticConfig:
      static: List of urls to probe
        - some_test_url
      labels:
    stage: Prod
    application: applicationxy
---
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Probe
metadata:
  name: 2xx-endpoints-how_I_want_it
spec:
  interval: 30s # Interval at which targets are probed
  module: http_2xx # Use the http_2xx module
  prober:
    url: blackbox: 9115 # Point to your blackbox instance, will always be blackbox: 9115 
  targets:
    staticConfig:
      static: List of urls to probe
        - some_url
      labels:
        stage: Test
    application: application11 
      static: # List of urls to probe
    - some_url_other_stage
    - some_url_other_stagel
      labels:
        stage: Acc
    application: application11
---

The problem is that the first block on the image shows the way it works for me, but I don't want to create from every stage and application a new block bc thats a lot.
I want to have one block for each application and within all the stages.
If I have it like the second block it only shows me the last static with "some_url_other_stage" and "some_url_other_stage1" but not the first with "some_url".
I was expecting to have in my Grafana the option to "filter" it in the query with the labels tag like -> labels="Test" and it shows me the "some_url" but it is not working

Hello @Philand and welcome. Your question references exact lines several times, but we do not see these lines, which makes your question difficult to read and understand.

@Rohlik sadly I am not allowed to embed the picture because I don't have enoth reputation. I Linked the picture behind the "->". I know this is not a great solution but I hope it will do the job for now... Sorry

Any help? Because I don't get any progress...

Questions with low readability usually have a lower chance of getting an answer. I recommend that you rewrite your question and put the mentioned lines of code directly into it as formatted code block.
